# function declaration returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, methods

here is the code:

```
   function findMin(min, max){
   console.log(Math.min(min,max) +100);
   }
   console.log(findMin(2,3));
```

However,along with the result ,it gives "undefined". Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

> However,along with the result ,it gives "undefined".

This is because the function is not explicitly returning any value.In that case it will always return `undefined`

Instead of consoling inside the function `return` the value

```js
function findMin(min, max) {
  return (Math.min(min, max) + 100);
}
console.log(findMin(2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log always returns undefined, in addition - you're not explicitly returning a specific value.  Instead, you should return the value itself, like:

```
function findMin(min, max){
  return Math.min(min,max) + 100;
}
console.log(findMin(2,3));
```